# In PowerShell, how can I exclude commented lines even though they include the pattern I am seeking to include?

Tags: regex, powershell, include, match

I am using a PowerShell script to read a file to get an assembly version, which I use to as part of an output file name.  However, the file I am reading also contains comments ("//"), which I would like to ignore.

Here are two lines from my input file.  The first is a comment line to be ignored, the second is a line with the desired value:

```
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Here's my current script:

```
 param (
    [string]$path
   ,[string]$file = "AssemblyInfo.cs"
   ,[string]$projectName)

# Search for the AssemblyVersion to be appended to the filename
$pattern = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
(Get-Content $path\$file) | ForEach-Object{
    if($_ -match $pattern){
        $fileVersion = [version]$matches[1]
    }
} 
Write-Host $projectName-$fileVersion
```

The current pattern matches on *both* lines of input.  Because the comment doesn't have a valid version, it produces an error:

```
Cannot convert value "1.0.*" to type "System.Version". 
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\Scripts\Powershell\Get-FileName.ps1:10 char:36
+         $fileVersion = [version]$matches[ <<<< 1]
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

How can I modify the $pattern value or the "if($_ -match $pattern)" in order to ignore commented lines?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the string you want to match will always be at the start of the line you can use the start of line marker (`^`) in your regular expression, which wouldn't match the commented line because of the slashes (`//`).

Your pattern would look like this:

```
$pattern = '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
```

Tests with -match

```
$oldRegex = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
$newRegex = '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'

'// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]' -match $oldRegex // returns True
'// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]' -match $newRegex // returns False
'[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]' -match $oldRegex // returns True
'[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]' -match $newRegex // returns True
```

Comment: The string I am matching might have spaces or tabs at the start.

Comment: then add \s* to the beggining of the regex. '^\s*\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'