# Powershell script: Regex to exclude commented code from string search in multiple files

Tags: regex, powershell, get-childitem

I am using `Get-ChildItem` to recursively parse through files in a folder to find certain strings.

I need a regex to exclude all forms of commented code from the search:

`/* Excluded */`

`/********Excluded***********/`

`//Excluded`

`/*` Excluded `*/`

`$My_Regex = "(?s)(?i)(^|\s+?)(\/\*)((.)(?!\*\/))*?(StringsToBeSearched)(.*?)(\*\/)"`

`$Searched_Results = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folderpath | Select-String $My_Regex`

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542425/in-powershell-how-can-i-exclude-commented-lines-even-though-they-include-the-pa) does not help.

The search needs to be on lines which are not part of any comments. Any help?

Powershell Version V5.1.

Comment: Are the target files source code files? You'll want to parse them according to their actual grammar and then only search the parts that aren't comments (or exclude the hits inside comment extents)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes. Difficult to comprehend. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I might. What language are the file contents written in?

Comment: A regex isn’t going to understand 100% what *is* a comment and what *isn’t* - for example in C#… ```var x = "xxx /* this is not a comment! */ yyy";```. Maybe your dataset won’t trigger these edge cases, but only a language parser will be able to understand the context enough to guarantee no false positives / negatives…

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Language is C.

Comment: Use Exclude Option in Get-ChildItem : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: @jdweng Isn't exclude only for the file types, not for contents of the file?

Comment: Isn't `/*  */` is a multiline comment, where `//` is a comment to the end of the line.  I think you would need 2 stages, with 2 regex, to do the job.  One would have to treat the file as a single line, the other would have to work on each line in the file.

Comment: @Darin I could manage the "...One would have to treat the file as a single line" part with a Get-ChildItem. But not the "...the other would have to work on each line in the file."

Comment: @Sandrocottus,, I think figured out away to remove all comments from a c file.  What exactly are you wanting stored in $Searched_Results?  An array of files, with each file a single string?  An array of lines, each line is a string, from all files?  A single large string containing all files, each file appended to the end of the string?  Other?

Comment: I should of suggested Where-Object and use -CNotLike property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it sounds straightforward it's a bit tricky. We could apply a technique called the trash can approach to solve this with Regex. The idea is to match everything we don't want in the overall match and only the thing we want in a group that gets extracted later, e.g.

```
(['"])(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*\1 #discard quoted string first
|\/\/[^\n\r]* # capture single line comments before mutli-line
|\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/ #c-style multi-line comment
|(StringsToBeSearched)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8h1dBz/1)

Unfortunately, Search-String works line-by-line and teaching it to treat the file as a single one (e.g. using the `(?s)` flag seems to fail in this instance. The below code works except for the match in the proper multi-line comment.

```
$rex = '(?s)"(?:(?!"|\\).|\\.)*"|\/\/[^\n\r]*|\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/|(StringsToBeSearched)'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\temp" | Select-String $rex | Where-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Success }
```

So, you are basically forced to read the file contents first. And while we are at it we could make this a bit easier but removing first everything we don't want and then search for the keyword like this:

```
$rex = '".*?"|(StringsToBeSearched)'
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\temp"))
{
    $fileContent = (Get-Content $file.PSPath -Raw) -join '' 
    $fileContent = $fileContent -replace '(?s)"(?:(?!"|\\).|\\.)*"|\/\/[^\n\r]*|\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/'
    $results = $fileContent | Select-String 'StringsToBeSearched' -AllMatches
    if($results.Matches.Success){
         Write-Host $file.Name
    }
}
```

If you do not only want the file name but also line numbers, etc you can easily extend the logic inside of the loop. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. Lastly, how can I pass multiple strings as variables to **StringsToBeSearched** parameter? For e.g, $StringsToBeSearched = "String1", "String2"... Then $rex = '(?s)"(?:(?!"|\\).|\\.)*"|\/\/[^\n\r]*|\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/|($StringsToBeSearched)'

Comment: You can use alternate groups to search for different sting
```$StringsToBeSearched = "String1", "String2"
$pipeSeparatedString = $StringsToBeSearched -join "|"
$rex = '(?s)"(?:(?!"|\).|\\.)*"|\/\/[^\n\r]*|\/*[^*]**+(?:[^\/*][^*]**+)*\/|(' + $pipeSeparatedString +')'```

Comment: Have you tried it like so? https://ideone.com/jA5Mp8